# Is there a way to secure the custom elements | HTML custom elements | Security

Tags: html, custom-element

I have a saas-based web application(create-resource.com) where an end user can perform CRUD operations on resources.

Now I want to allow them to use my custom element i.e a button so they can embed that button on their custom website(customer-site.com). When the user on the customer's website clicks on the button it will create a resource on my web application on the behalf of the customer(the customer's unique id is ABC).

So I create a [custom element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_custom_elements) which extended the button (HTMLelement) and a js file to load that element. now based on the id(i.e customer-abc) I can get the idea that the resource should be created under which customer.

***example (customer-site.com/index.html)***

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="create-resource.com/embed.js" />
    </head>
<body>
    <create-resource text="Build a resource" id="customer-abc">
</body>
</html>
```

Real Problem - If any user knows the unique id(or key) of the customer, so he can easily embed my custom element on their website and create the resource on the behalf of that customer.

Is there any way so I can secure the custom element and only the real customer actually perform the operations?

Comment: Your `<script />` tag is invalid. No HTML element needs or requires a closing slash but that tag needs a closing tag: `<script></script>`

Comment: well, that is just pseudo code to give you the general idea. But I request you to focus on the real problem.

Comment: Basically, implementing authorization in publically visible properties is no good idea at all. Perhaps think about an authentication process that grants access to your site (or ressource) to customers only. In short: make the user supply some sort of credentials, hand them back a session token. When the user clicks your button, send the token along with the payload to the server and check it's validity. 
You don't have to do the heavy lifting yourself, maybe https://github.com/pwa-builder/pwa-auth is a way to g for you.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS